# Could you help me prove this information theory inequality

Tags: inequality, information-theory

Greetings and many thanks in advance.

Let $h(p)=-p\log_2 p-\bar{p}\log_2 \bar{p}$ be the binary entropy function, where $\bar{p}=1-p$. Prove that $$(1-h(p))h(x)-h(p*x)+h(p)\geq 0,\forall x\in [0,1],$$
where $p*x=p\bar{x}+x\bar{p}.$

It is trivial to see that we can only check $x\in [0,1/2]$. And also, I plotted the graph of the LHS function, [image: Plot of the LHS function and its first & second derivatives]

Comment: Equivalent to $H(X | X+Y) \ge H(X)H(Y)$ where $X,Y$ are independent (not iid) Bernoulli variables, the sum is $\pmod 2$ (XOR) and the entropies are in bits. I doubt this helps, though

Comment: Taking derivatives helps.

Comment: I solved this. Thanks everyone.